# No Web_Id in MailChimp API V3

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am in the process of upgrading a Mailchimp integration to use the latest version of the API (V3).

In V2 of the API, campaign objects had a Web_Id, which was an integer and could be used to create a browsable URL link.

EG: `admin.mailchimp.com/reports/show?id=Web_Id`

I cannot find Web_Id or its equivalent anywhere in the V3 API documentation.

Does anyone know if it is still possible to retrieve this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too was looking for this value when working with the `/lists` endpoint in v3. It turns out that the web_id is actually returned in the response header:

```
Link: <https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/Instance.json>; rel="describedBy", <https://us13.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/members/?id=[web_id]>; rel="dashboard"
```

It's worth noting that if this endpoint returns a collection, like `/lists` does, the header will not contain the web app URLs, they are only present when getting, in this case, a single list, e.g. `/lists/[list_id]`

I imagine that the value is also present for single campaign objects returned by the API.

Comment: Yeah it is the same for single campaign objects. Thanks